# Can I remove an Azure VM from an Availability Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I can't find any instructions on how to remove an azure VM from an availability set. Is this even possible or do I have to delete then re-create the VM with the existing disks?

I have some VMs witch where created as single instances in availability sets, and want to remove them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/availability-set?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 1):

in ARM: The availability set can only be configured when creating a virtual machine. You must recreate the virtual machine to move it in or out of an availability set.

Answer (score 0):

You can add, or remove, a VM to/from an availability set without deleting/re-creating.

If you're using PowerShell, you have:

- `Remove-AzureAvailabilitySet` for classic VMs
- `Remove-AzureRmAvailabilitySet` for Resource Manager VMs

Likewise, you can do this in the portal. For example, here's one of my 'classic' VMs in an availability set:

[image: avail set]

The highlighted blue box shows that my VM is in an availability set. To remove it, I just select the item above it (`Not part of an availability set`) and save:

[image: removing availability set]

Comment: 'Remove-AzureRmAvailabilitySet' is for deleting an Availability Set not removing VMs from a set.

And as you can see from this screenshot the UI does not provide a way of removing an existing VM from a set
http://i.imgur.com/p2FMeGp.png

I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is No you cannot remove an exising VM from an Availability set.